# How to iterate through JSON dictonary with Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, loops, parsing

My code is this

```
    with open('base.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)

    for Object in data["Objects"][0]:
        print(Object["Name"])
```

Im trying to be able to print

```
SellMenu
BuyMenu
```

So I can add buttons to specific menus but this code isn't working and it crashes
My JSON(base.json) is

```
{
    "Objects": [
    {
        "Type": "Menu",
        "Path": "insert_path",
        "Name": "SellMenu",
        "X": 0,
        "Y": 0,
        "Width": 1920,
        "Height": 1080,
        "Buttons": [],
        "Text": []
    },
    {
        "Type": "Menu",
        "Path": "insert_path",
        "Name": "BuyMenu",
        "X": 0,
        "Y": 0,
        "Width": 1920,
        "Height": 1080,
        "Buttons": [],
        "Text": []
    }]
}
```

Comment: Remove the `[0]` from `data["Objects"][0]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
for Object in data["Objects"]:
    print(Object["Name"])
```

#### Explanation:

By doing this `for Object in data["Objects"][0]:`, actually you trying to iterate the first element in the list.
In order to iterate the list itself, you have to write `for Object in data["Objects"]:`. Indeed, the type of `data["Objects"]` is list.

Comment: @KyleKip Are you sure? It works for me. What is the result/error you get?

Comment: @ThunderPhenix If Im trying to add to the second dictionary by using ```data["Objects"][0]["Buttons"].append``` How would I do that? right now it just adds to the first one

Comment: @KyleKip I don't understand your question. Try to be explicit.

Comment: Ok So I have 2 menus one ```SellMenu``` and ```BuyMenu``` both have a ```Buttons[]``` In my python code I'm using this line to append to the JSON file ```data["Objects"][0]["Buttons"].append({"RX": ButtonObject.x, "RY": ButtonObject.y, "Width": ButtonObject.width, "Height" : ButtonObject.height, "Path": ButtonObject.path, "Name" : ButtonObject.name})``` When ever I call this it add to the first ```Buttons[]``` it finds which isn't the correct one. How can I specify which one to use. Not sure how to tell it to go to the ```BuyMenu``` or ```SellMenu```

Comment: @KyleKip Use `data["Objects"][0]...` for `SellMenu` and `data["Objects"][1] ...` for `BuyMenu`

Answer (score 0):

Using the same contents in my `test.json` file as you have posted, this function currently does as ask. Now I just want to point out that `Object` is a reserved keyword in python and that may be causing a conflict here:

```
def jsonTest():
    import json
    with open('test.json', 'r') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    for element in data['Objects']:
        print(element['Name'])

jsonTest()
```

**Output:**

```
> python .\testing.py
SellMenu
BuyMenu
```

By using the zeroth index of the data['Objects'][0] list you are asking the iterator to loop over the following:

```
    for element in data['Objects'][0]:
        print(f'Element: {element:8s} <==> Type: {type(element)}')
```

Which you can see by the output that it's not a `key` for a dictionary, it's a string.
**Output:**

```
> python .\testing.py
Element: Type     <==> Type: <class 'str'>
Element: Path     <==> Type: <class 'str'>
Element: Name     <==> Type: <class 'str'>
Element: X        <==> Type: <class 'str'>
Element: Y        <==> Type: <class 'str'>
Element: Width    <==> Type: <class 'str'>
Element: Height   <==> Type: <class 'str'>
Element: Buttons  <==> Type: <class 'str'>
Element: Text     <==> Type: <class 'str'>
```

Therefore you need to iterator over the `data['Objects']` list.

```
for element in data['Objects']:
        print(f'Type: {type(element)}\nDict: {element}')
```

**Output:**

```
> python .\testing.py
Type: <class 'dict'>
Dict: {'Type': 'Menu', 'Path': 'insert_path', 'Name': 'SellMenu', 'X': 0, 'Y': 0, 'Width': 1920, 'Height': 1080, 'Buttons': [], 'Text': []}
Type: <class 'dict'>
Dict: {'Type': 'Menu', 'Path': 'insert_path', 'Name': 'BuyMenu', 'X': 0, 'Y': 0, 'Width': 1920, 'Height': 1080, 'Buttons': [], 'Text': []}
```

Which would then give you access to normal dictionary operations. Hopefully that makes sense.

**Edit**:
In order to append a dictionary to the end of the dictionary, you can do it individually by utilizing some form of for loop to add each element, or you can use the `extend` method for dictionary with something as follows:

```
data['Objects'][0]['Buttons'].extend({"RX": ButtonObject.x, "RY": ButtonObject.y, "Width": ButtonObject.width, "Height" : ButtonObject.height, "Name" : ButtonObject.name}).extend({"RX": ButtonObject.x, "RY": ButtonObject.y, "Width": ButtonObject.width, "Height" : ButtonObject.height, "Name" : ButtonObject.name})
```

The problem here is that by default ['Buttons'] is a list `[]` not a dictionary `{}`, so with dynamic typing you can just re-type (re declare the type) by assigning it to that new type (`=`):
**Output:**

```
>>> d = {'Type': 'Menu', 'Path': 'insert_path', 'Name': 'SellMenu', 'X': 0, 'Y': 0, 'Width': 1920, 'Height': 1080, 'Buttons': [], 'Text': []}
>>> d['Buttons']
[]

>>> d['Buttons'] = {"RX": 123, "RY": 321, "Width": 10, "Height" : 73, "Name" : 'Robin'}
>>> d['Buttons']
{'RX': 123, 'RY': 321, 'Width': 10, 'Height': 73, 'Name': 'Robin'}
```

Always happy to help!

Comment: Oh that makes so much sense thank you! Quick question. If I wanted to add something like ```data["Objects"][0]["Buttons"].append({"RX": ButtonObject.x, "RY": ButtonObject.y, "Width": ButtonObject.width, "Height" : ButtonObject.height, "Name" : ButtonObject.name})``` this to either the SellMenu or BuyMenu How can I explicitly say that?